# getIntent() in onResume() always returns same action, how to consume it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm showing a notification with an intent like this:

```
Intent intentOpen = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intentOpen.setAction("ACTION_SHOW_BACKUP_FRAGMENT");
intentOpen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntentOpen = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentOpen, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntentOpen);
```

As you can see, the action is set to `"ACTION_SHOW_BACKUP_FRAGMENT"`, so that when the user clicks in the notification, my **singleTop** MainActivity can get the action in the `onResume()` method with `getIntent().getAction()`.

In order for this to work I had to implement `onNewIntent()` like this:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

So far, so good, the action is received and I can show the backup view. But then if I press the home button, so that the app goes to the background, and then enter on it again via the recent apps menu, the `onResume()` method is called again but the `"ACTION_SHOW_BACKUP_FRAGMENT"` action is still there! **So I cannot differentiate if the user really clicked on the notification or is just resuming the app**.

I have tried solving the issue with a log of combinations of Intent and PendingIntent flags but nothing worked. I also tried calling `setIntent(new Intent());` after using the action in `onResume()` but `onNewIntent()` still gets the `"ACTION_SHOW_BACKUP_FRAGMENT"` action the next time I resume the app.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the right combination of flags for the Intent and PendingIntent:

```
// Create pending intent to open the backup fragment
intentOpen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntentOpen = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentOpen, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

This works while I still *consume* the intent in `onResume()` with `setIntent(null);`

Comment: the flag PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT is very important otherwise you will receive in you intentOpen always  same old parameters like you set them for the first time